# Issues in x-cart 4.6.1 (Mysql support)

Tags: php, mysql

I have downloaded x-cart 4.6.1, After downloaded i moved to the folder in localhost and opened the link "localhost/xcart/" for installing i got error in mysql support [mysql support issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGS9n.png) . Any other solution is there to fix it.

In my php.ini file, below are existing in without semicolon (;)
`extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use PHP7 ?

In this case you have to install this patch php70x-2016-10-25_4.6.1.tgz.

The archive can be found at
X-Cart -> X-Cart supporting files for prev versions -> 4.6.x -> 4.6.1 -> Updates and patches

Try this 
http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Applying_Patches#To_apply_a_patch_by_issuing_the_command_.27patch.27

**Update**

X-Cart 4.6.1 does not support PHP7 by default.

I have uploaded a patched x-cart-4.6.1gold.php7.tgz here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4o4tu0kh8hmzt9/x-cart-4.6.1gold.php7.tgz?dl=0

Comment: Yes I am using PHP 7. But I did not upgrade X-cart. I have downloaded freshly and trying to install first time. at the time i am facing above issue